# How to set path for argparse within a python file without command line

Tags: python, argparse

I am using argparse to run my python file which will deal with 3 different directories. now I want that the last "--output" path to my directory to be initialized and not given by run command line. So that I run my python file by just giving the paths for "--cascade" directory and "--encodings".The path which I want to give to "--output" directory is "/home/pi/pi-face-recognition/dataset/New".

Therefore advise me how can I set the output path within the argparse and I dont need to give this in commandline while running my python file

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-c", "--cascade", required=True,
    help = "path to where the face cascade resides")
ap.add_argument("-e", "--encodings", required=True,
    help="path to serialized db of facial encodings")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True,
    help="path to output directory /home/pi/pi-face recognition/dataset/New")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

This is the code section which will save images from the camera and store into this output directory.

```
p = os.path.sep.join([args["output"], "{}.png".format(
    str(total).zfill(5))])
cv2.imwrite(p, orig)
total += 1
```

Comment: "and I dont need to give this in commandline while running my python file" - if you want to use this path and not give the user the ability to change it, just use a regular variable which'll hold a string with the path

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's a bit hard to tell what you're looking for. Could you [edit] and add the value of `sys.argv[1:]` before parsing, and the namespace that you want argparse to output? See [mre] for more details.

Comment: Please see the code I have edited. I want to store images in this default output directory  without having to enter this path while running my python file using Linux terminal

Comment: Print `args` after parsing so you have a clear idea of what the parser produced.  Changing the `default` and `required` should work.  Also the default default is `None`, which is easy to test for.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean setting a default value for `--output`, can use the `default` parameter to `add_argument` (probably need to drop `required=True` for this):

```py
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", default="/home/pi/pi-face recognition/dataset/New", help="path to output directory /home/pi/pi-face recognition/dataset/New")
```

Otherwise, can use the `args` parameter of `ap.parse_args()`, e.g. like so:

```py
import sys
args = vars(ap.parse_args(args=sys.argv[1:] + ['--output', '<directory>']))
```

Note that need to drop the script path which is in `sys.argv[0]`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used the first approach but still my code doesn't save results (images) into the output directory unless I define this output path (--output /home/pi/pi-face recognition/dataset/New) in command line on terminal while running this python file. I also dropped "Required True"

Comment: Is there a difference in imwrite parameters when supplying / not supplying the parameter? Default argument value as above works for me in python 3.6